# Would a digital potentiometer be viable to control a OKL-T/6-W12P-C?

Tags: arduino, dc-dc-converter, digital-potentiometer

I have a few on hand and I would like to control the output voltage with an arduino. Maybe with a digital potentiometer, but the [datasheet](https://www.murata.com/products/productdata/8807038255134/okl-t6-w12.pdf?1583754815000) calls for fairly strict wiring with short leads and little noise. Is there a better way to approach this? Should I use a different module and if so where should I look? Sorry if this isn't the correct way to ask I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: It'll degrade the step response of the supply but within reason it'll probably be ok.  If you're worried, you can use an analog output pin on the Arduino and a resistor to generate current with relatively little parasitic capacitance.

Comment: Most Arduinos do not have an analog output but they do have PWM which with a low pass filter can become analog voltage. The DUO has I believe 2 true analog outputs which are created with its interhan DAC. A digital pot should be fine. Normally you would not constantly be programming it which is the point it would probably generate the most noise.